# Issue with GEO_CONTAINS

Tags: arangodb

I am looking at 3.4 RC with a view to outputting full GeoJSON files. Using the example of restaurants and neighbourhoods ie https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-training-center/geojson-tutorial/ I can append the neighbourhood if I filter to a single neighbourhood but get "invalid loop in polygon" if I remove the name filter.

```
FOR n IN neighborhoods
FILTER n.name == "Chinatown" 

FOR restaurant IN restaurants
FILTER GEO_CONTAINS(n.geometry, restaurant.location) 
return
{type:"Feature","geometry":restaurant.location,
"properties":{"neighbourhood":n.name,"name":restaurant.name}}
```

Is this my inexperience with ArangoDB or an issue in 3.4?

Comment: Arghh, problem with the collection not the AQL. All sorted.

Comment: How did you solve the problem exactly? (You can post it as answer and it accept it later)